# How to use a tint as an accent color on my Progress Bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, accent-color

I do manage to change the progress bar color but it appears darker than expected.

I get a very dark red instead of a light pink.

I use Safari as my browser.

```css
progress {
  accent-color: #ffc7d4;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  accent-color: #ffc7d4;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  accent-color: #ffc7d4;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  accent-color: #ffc7d4;
}
```

```html
<h3>Accent color for a progress element:</h3>
<label for="file">Downloading progress:</label>
<progress id="file" value="72" max="100">72%</progress>
```

Comment: Must be a Safari issue, Firefox/Edge on W10-x64 show the proper pink hex value.

Comment: @Rene van der Lende yes. It actually looks nicer in Chrome. It darkens the background bar so the pink looks very bold. I think the reason why Safari is not allowing it is because I need styling for the background bar as well. maybe

Comment: Firefox has a `#e9e9ed` track, proper pink, Edge has a dark/black track, but also proper pink.

Comment: @Rene van der Lende so it's not a good practice to use light pink because Safari doesn't cover it.

Comment: No idea, I have no Apple devices. Maybe change the track color? Or just ignore the issue as a whole, there are probably more important issues to solve anyway.

Comment: It's odd because Safari can and does show the correct colour, but just not in the progress element

Comment: It is odd @evolutionxbox